# Subtract grouped aggregate column by another in 3 table join query

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

I'm pretty new to joinings and advanced querying, what I want to do is to join three tables to make an summary of how many hours an employee has spent on courses (course data is omitted from examples).

!-SQL query is below the example table-!

**The query must show:**

- A unique set of employee name.
- Their individual allocated hours.
- A sum of their hours spent
- And return a final new column showing the allowance left.

---

- **"employees" table**

| id | employee_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Annachiara Darius" |
| 2 | "Samar Rajani" |
| 3 | "Taonga Eric" |
| 4 | "Tycho Sigdag" |
| 5 | "Naevius Matvei" |
| 6 | "Theophania Eglantine" |
| 7 | "Boro Stanislav" |

- **"accounting" table where hours are recorded**

| id | employee_id | hours_done |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2.50 |
| 2 | 1 | 2.80 |
| 3 | 2 | 5.60 |
| 4 | 2 | 3.30 |
| 5 | 4 | 4.50 |
| 6 | 5 | 8.90 |
| 7 | 6 | 7.60 |
| 8 | 3 | 6.50 |
| 9 | 7 | 1.00 |
| 10 | 5 | 10.30 |
| 11 | 7 | 11.50 |
| 12 | 5 | 5.60 |
| 13 | 7 | 100.00 |
| 14 | 2 | 30.00 |

- **"allocation" table**

| id | employee_id | hours_allocated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 2 | 16 |
| 3 | 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 4 | 15 |
| 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 6 | 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 7 | 8 |

```
    SELECT ACCOUNTING.EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE_NAME,
    ALLOCATED.HOURS_ALLOCATED,
    SUM(ACCOUNTING.HOURS_DONE) AS HOURS_SPENT,
    SUM(ALLOCATED.HOURS_ALLOCATED - ACCOUNTING.HOURS_DONE) AS ALLOWANCE
FROM PUBLIC.ACCOUNTING ACCOUNTING
INNER JOIN
                (SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME,
                        EMPLOYEE_ID
                    FROM PUBLIC.EMPLOYEES GROUP
            BY EMPLOYEE_ID) EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = ACCOUNTING.EMPLOYEE_ID
INNER JOIN
                (SELECT HOURS_ALLOCATED,
                        EMPLOYEE_ID
                    FROM PUBLIC.ALLOCATION GROUP
      BY EMPLOYEE_ID,
                        HOURS_ALLOCATED) ALLOCATED ON ALLOCATED.EMPLOYEE_ID = ACCOUNTING.EMPLOYEE_ID GROUP
    BY ACCOUNTING.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME,
    ALLOCATED.HOURS_ALLOCATED
ORDER
    BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ASC
```

- **Result from the query above**

| employee_id | employee_name | hours_allocated | hours_spent | allowance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Annachiara Darius" | 12 | 5.3 | 18.7 |
| 7 | "Boro Stanislav" | 8 | 112.5 | -88.5 |
| 5 | "Naevius Matvei" | 10 | 24.8 | 5.2 |
| 2 | "Samar Rajani" | 16 | 38.9 | 9.1 |
| 3 | "Taonga Eric" | 20 | 6.5 | 13.5 |
| 6 | "Theophania Eglantine" | 7 | 7.6 | -0.6 |
| 4 | "Tycho Sigdag" | 15 | 4.5 | 10.5 |

As you can see I've managed to get every column displaying the information I wanted correctly.
The problem:

- Allowence column is only correct if the employee has only made one entry in the accounting table.
- If employee has more than one entry in accounting the calculation is off/wrong.

The line I use to get the allowance is

- **SUM(ALLOCATED.HOURS_ALLOCATED - ACCOUNTING.HOURS_DONE) AS ALLOWANCE**

I've been trying different stuff but can't seem to manage this part of the query.
How can I incorporate this into the group logic?

Comment: `ALLOCATED.HOURS_ALLOCATED - SUM(ACCOUNTING.HOURS_DONE)`?

Comment: That's correct, thank so much :) Those little things that mess you up haha.

Comment: @IngimarEyfjordSmarason . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was posted in a comment.

`ALLOCATED.HOURS_ALLOCATED - SUM(ACCOUNTING.HOURS_DONE)` is correct
but not

```
`SUM(ALLOCATED.HOURS_ALLOCATED - ACCOUNTING.HOURS_DONE)` AS ALLOWANCE
```